# ¿Database Db2 tiene alguna especie de borrado en cascada por default o Por que sucede esto?

Tags: sql, db2

Disculpen si la pregunta es bastante básica. Empecé hace poco con Db2 así que aun no lo conozco muy bien. La pregunta va dirigida a una situación. Según tengo entendido (o por lo menos con mi experiencia de SQL command line) es que si existe una llave primaria haciendo referencia a una tabla externa como foranea, es imposible borrar dicha tabla con la llave primaria ya que sus datos son necesarios para los de la otra tabla, sin embargo cuando borro dicha tabla en db2 esta se borra sin ningún problema a pesar de existir esta relacion ¿Hay algo activo por default que haga que ocurra esto o a que se debe?

Por si se requiere:

```
CREATE TABLE Genero (id_genero  NUMERIC(1) NOT NULL, nombre_genero CHAR NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id_genero), CONSTRAINT CHK_Genero CHECK (nombre_genero = 'M' OR nombre_genero ='F'))
INSERT INTO Genero VALUES (1, 'M')
CREATE TABLE Alumno (n_control  NUMERIC(8) NOT NULL, id_genero  NUMERIC(1) NOT NULL, nombre_alumno  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, apellido_paterno VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, apellido_materno  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, fecha_nacimiento  DATE NULL, numero_telefono  NUMERIC(14) NULL, correo_electronico  VARCHAR(70) NULL, semestre  NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(n_control),CONSTRAINT FK_IDGENERO_ALUMNO FOREIGN KEY (id_genero) REFERENCES Genero(id_genero))
INSERT INTO Alumno VALUES (19051196, 1, 'Angel Daniel', 'Rodriguez', 'Juarez', null, null, null, 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación: cuando se elimina un objeto cualquier otro que sea de alguna manera dependiente al mismo puede ser **eliminado** o marcado como **inoperativo**.

> The DROP statement deletes an object. Any objects that are directly or indirectly dependent on that object are either deleted or made inoperative. Whenever an object is deleted, its description is deleted from the catalog, and any packages that reference the object are invalidated.

[DB2 DROP](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=s-drop)

En tu caso se está eliminando la tabla "Genero" y como la restricción "FK_IDGENERO_ALUMNO" depende de la misma pues es eliminada. Si te fijas luego del borrado de "Genero" puedes insertar un alumno con el id 2.

Puedes ver la ejecución de las pruebas acá:

[drop table fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=e326fb97680d335303b37a1581685972)

Resulta un poco extraño el comportamiento, no pude encontrar alguna manera de bloquearlo desde la creación de la tabla, ya que en la documentación de los constraints indican que se puede usar RESTRICT como opción de ON DELETE pero solo se toma en cuenta cuando se elimina una fila de la tabla "*padre*" y no para cuando se elimina la tabla como tal.

Así que para responder a tu pregunta, sí, es el comportamiento normal de DB2.